# ViewController objects invalid when performFetchWithCompletionHandler called

Tags: ios, swift

I received a crash report from a tester where my main user object created by my MasterViewController was (apparently) nil or invalid when the OS called performFetchWithCompletionHandler. I know that this object was initialized when the app went into the background because I don't request background fetch notifications unless I'm in a certain state that requires the User object to be valid.

Here is a snippet of the create of the MasterViewController:

```
class MasterViewController: UITableViewController {

static var services = [Service]()
static var user:User!
.
.
.

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Create model objects
    MasterViewController.user = User()
   .
   .
   .

}
```

And here is the fetch call using the user object:

```
func application(application: UIApplication, performFetchWithCompletionHandler completionHandler: (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void) {

    print("Background notification: In performFetchWithCompletionHandler")

    if MasterViewController.user.getProviderState() == ProviderState.Offline ||
        !UserAPIManager.sharedInstance.isLoggedIn {

        print("Replied with .NoData")
        completionHandler (.NoData)

    } else {
       .
       .
       .
    }
}
```

The crash was on the line:

```
if MasterViewController.user.getProviderState() == ProviderState.Offline ||
        !UserAPIManager.sharedInstance.isLoggedIn
```

The exception type I'm getting is - Exception Type:  SIGTRAP  (This test program is built in debug).

I have never seen this error running in the debugger while forcing the app to go into the background.

Also, I am not freeing this User object in didReceiveMemoryWarning().

Thanks for any insight anyone might have.

Comment: "I have never seen this error running in the debugger while forcing the app to go into the background." Are you testing in the simulator or on the device? The simulator does not cut it here.

Comment: Are you relying on the app being backgrounded but still running? Perhaps the function was called after a device restart.

Comment: This dump was sent to me from a tester's phone, not the simulator. It must have been in the background because the stack trace pointed to the line inside of performFetchWithCompletionHandler. I don't request the fetch when being put into the background without having a valid User object. I have put check around the code to make sure the pointer is not nil so that will prevent the crash, but I'm puzzled as to how it ever became nil. I assume that the object will remain valid even when in the background. I was wondering if perhaps the OS freed some of my objects.